# Create stored procedure that contains newlines with a oneliner sql statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I want to put code in a single line that will create a stored procedure that contains newlines.

- Is that possible?
- Do I need to use sp_executesql?
- How do I escape newlines in a sql statement?
- How do I escape newlines in a string?

Comment: So you need to include carriage return and new line characters in your stored procedure, but not in your CREATE statement?

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: May we ask why?

Comment: To get one command per line resulting in a cleaner file.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can do something like this with dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';
DECLARE @NewLine NCHAR(1) = NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SELECT * ' + @NewLine + N'FROM sys.databases AS d ' + @NewLine + N'WHERE d.database_id > 4;' + @NewLine;

PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: @AndersLindén yep, don't put a + before EXEC.

Comment: I was trying to put the + in the argument to exec, building the sql string there

Comment: @Anders um, why?

Comment: The parameter of sp_executesql must be either a variable or a constant.  No expressions allowed.

Comment: Is there no way of escaping characters in a t-sql string?

Comment: Do you want to get the results of the 'one line' string and execute them yourself afterwards? Just issue a select of the string and show the results as text instead of results to grid in ssms? You can use the same @NewLine variable in your select, but if you want to directly execute the create proc statement then you will have to use EXEC sys.sp_executesql.

Answer (score 0):

No, T-SQL cannot escape newlines, tabs, etc. It only has an escape sequence for embedded string delimiters: `''` = `'`. There is also an escape sequence for delimited identifiers: either `""` for `"`, or `]]` for `]`, depending on which one is being used to delimit the identifier.

If you want to work with escape sequences, you can do so manually via the `REPLACE` function.

Depending on how the "single line of code" is being interpreted, you can do either:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TestProc') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE #TestProc;
END;
GO

-- The following is technically a single line (with multiple commands):
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'CREATE PROCEDURE #TestProc\n(\n  @Param1 INT,\n  @Param2 NVARCHAR(128)\n)\nAS\nSET NOCOUNT ON;\n\nSELECT *\nFROM   tempdb.sys.sql_modules\nWHERE  [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N''tempdb..'' + @Param2);'; SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, N'\n', NCHAR(10)); EXEC (@SQL);

-- View the definition:
PRINT @SQL;

-- Test the proc:
EXEC #TestProc 2, N'#TestProc';
```

Or, if you can only execute a single command/statement, then you can try the following:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TestProc2') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP PROCEDURE #TestProc2;
END;
GO

-- The following is a single line and a single statement:
EXEC (N'DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N''CREATE PROCEDURE #TestProc2\n(\n  @Param1 INT,\n  @Param2 NVARCHAR(128)\n)\nAS\nSET NOCOUNT ON;\n\nSELECT *\nFROM   tempdb.sys.sql_modules\nWHERE  [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N''''tempdb..'''' + @Param2);''; SET @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, N''\n'', NCHAR(10)); EXEC (@SQL);');

-- Test the proc:
EXEC #TestProc2 2, N'#TestProc2';

-- View the definition:
DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @SQL2 = [definition]
FROM   tempdb.sys.sql_modules
WHERE  [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#TestProc2');

PRINT @SQL2;
-- returns (in "Messages" tab):
/*
CREATE PROCEDURE #TestProc2
(
  @Param1 INT,
  @Param2 NVARCHAR(128)
)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT *
FROM   tempdb.sys.sql_modules
WHERE  [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..' + @Param2);
*/
```